# Observing private properties in Sproutcore

Tags: javascript, sproutcore, sproutcore-views

Is it possible to observe private (underscored ) properties from 
within the object itself? 
I need to know when _view_layer is getting set, so that I can apply 
some jQuery even handlers. Unfortunately init() and render() are 
really early, so _view_layer is undefined. 
Unfortunately, observing _view_layer doesn't seem to work as well. 
Please, tell me what I can do. Basically, if there is another possible 
solution, I am open to see that as well

Comment: What exactly are you talking about here?  Where is this "private" property?

Comment: An underscore (_) in javascript does not mean that the property is private.  Take for instance: `var a = { _p : 'test' };`  I can still access `a._p;`  Thus, I'm a bit perplexed as to what you are talking about.  And what baffles me even more is "init() and render() are really early."  I honestly have no clue what that means.

Comment: I haven't heard of a way to automatically track changes to an object. What if you create a method to use when you want to change _view_layer and each time it is called you can execute additional jquery stuff alongside the changes to _view_layer?

Comment: I know, but Sproutcore does not take them into consideration when updating bindings and observers

Comment: which version of sproutcore are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sproutcore the underscore is only a *convention* that the property/method is private.  Its not actually private.

In Sproutcore, the views have life-cycle methods.  This one might be of interest (taken from SC 1.4.5 code in view):

> - *didCreateLayer:* the render() method is used to generate new HTML.
>     Override this method to perform any additional setup on the DOM you
>     might
>     need to do after creating the view.  For example, if you need to
>     listen
>     for events.

Views have changed drastically in SC 1.6 and later, but I believe that `didCreateLayer` is still recognized.

Comment: Thing is ... this method works, but the 'this' scope points to the whole HTML document, instead of the current view. How can I request the current instance in another way?

Comment: @user802232 i would need to see the code.  If you are trying to attach handlers in a view you defined, 'this' should point to the view context.

Comment: code is pretty straightforward. I added a method called didCreateLayer in every view where I needed additional handling. However, the 'this' inside it points to the main HTML document, instead of the view ret object itself

Comment: @user802332, that makes no sense.  nothing would work if that were true.  Please post some code with comments as to where 'this' is the main html document.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1035760 Look around line 23. None of these manipulations work, because simply 'this' is not pointing to the view context

Comment: @user802332, after looking at your code, I can't figure out why 'this' would be the window.  I tried in my own code, I put a breakpoint in and typed this === window in the console, and got false.  That said, you don't need to define those event handlers in didCreateLayer -- just put mouseEntered: function(evt) and mouseExited: function(evt) methods on the view itself.  You only need to do that in didCreateLayer if you are attaching event handlers to divs that are children of the view.  In your case, the event handlers are on the view layer itself, not on children.

Comment: @user802332, i just saw " $(document).ready(function() {" in your code.  Why are you doing that?  Dont do that.  the didCreateLayer fires when the view DOM has been appended to the window, it will fire only after the view is 'ready'.

Comment: OMG!!! How could I be so stupid. Thanks a million, I must be really tired not to notice that

Comment: @user802232 -- np -- thats why we are here. ;) glad we got your issues sorted....

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
  var value = obj._view_layer;
  delete obj._view_layer;
  var callback = function() {
    /* observation logic */
  }
  Object.defineProperty(obj, "_view_layer", {
    get: function() {
      return value;
    },
    set: function(val) {
      value = val;
      callback(val);
    },
    writable: true, 
    enumerable: true

  });
})();
```

Requires an ES5 browser.

Only recommended to use for debugging. You can also use [`.watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) when debugging in firefox.